# 'Preserve'/refer to variable names when passed as arguments

Tags: c#, variables, pointers, string-interpolation

Using string interpolation, I'm attempting to write a method which iterates over an arbitrary amount of objects to evaluating both the name and value of each.

So, consider the following:

```
    private string ParametersMessage(params object[] parameters)
    {
        var msg = "Parameters: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            msg += $"{nameof(parameters[i])}:{parameters[i]}\r\n";
        }

        return msg;
    }
```

You can't tell from the StackOverflow syntax highlighting - but this ain't working, not in a million years, because `parameters[i]` has no name, so `nameof` can't do the job.

I may call this method like so:

```
int myNumber = 123;
string myWord = "hello";

var myMessage = ParametersMessage(myNumber, myWord);
```

Now since I've passed `myNumber` and `myWord` as arguments, they've lost their name.  Do I need to pass a pointer or some other way of referring to the variable name? How can I build a string from each of the objects' names and values in the list?

### Context

During logging, I'll often concatenate a whole host of parameter names and values to help diagnose issues more specifically by seeing which particular record/object failed XYZ. I'm trying to make my method generic enough to avoid having to write many string builder methods.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried the above (you can see my attempt), but I've also considered passing in the result of `nameof` *with* the value. But at that point, I've quickly reverted back to making it too specific again.

### Note

I'm no expert, but I'm experienced enough to know the above syntax is silly. I suppose you could interpret my question as 'offer me an alternative approach to what I'm illustrating with my code sample above'.

Comment: If it's array, than names are important anymore, thus no string interpolation is needed. You can use a Dictionary, which will easily solve your issue.

Comment: There is no way to do that.  You could change it to use expression trees, though.

Comment: Names are important to the business logic, though. I appreciate passing them in as an array is opting to lose reference to names etc. so I'm asking how I can pass them differently/approach it differently.

Comment: @SLaks - expression trees sound nice. I'll look into it.

Comment: I've edited my Original comment, @SLaks, Dictionary wouldn't be more natural ?

Comment: A dictionary would, indeed, but then I'm calling `nameof` per object again, and so the arguments I'm passing would look familiar to that of a string concatenation. The idea was to pass this a list of parameters, and build a string. I can see this is impossible from the syntax I currently have.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, My intention were, to direct you to Dictionary in order for you to use the `Key` instead of the variable name.

Comment: @OrelEraki yep, I see, it's not a bad idea, but populating that dictionary would be no more 'elegant' than manually building the string.

Comment: This is what everybody is aiming for when writing a logger (and let's face it: We've all done it, and we've all thought we could do better than what's already out there). And it's what everybody, eventually, fails to achieve. As a suggestion: **IF** you also include the name of the method (through "CallerMemberName" for instance), then just dumping the array, and possibly including actual type of the value, might give you sufficient information about what got passed in for what parameter, without knowing the actual name.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt - I like that idea of using types. It's not quite an answer to retrieving the names, but it's a great point.

Comment: For name retrieval you would indeed need a Dictionary or expression trees as SLaks suggested, but it's not going to be pretty, and at the very least tedious. Can't win'm all ;)

Comment: And, in the end, you want something logged with sufficient information to trace what went wrong *in the software that you're actually building but is now on halt because it's waiting for the Ultimate Logger to be build* ;)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt - certainly can't. I think I'm flogging a dead horse here. If something's to tedious, it may mean it's expensive. And I certainly don't want that.

Comment: I've updated my answer: although it is not necessarily elegant, maybe you can get something from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

And the signature of the method gives it away: From the compilers point of view , and for all practical purposes, it's an anonymized array of values, with no names associated with them.

And to more clearly illustrate, let's for the sake of argument assume you were to call it like:

```
ParametersMessage(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

What would the parameter names be in that case?

Comment: Ahh, valid point about passing in arguments 'without a name'. Didn't think of that! I've given you an upvote, but I would rather accept an alternative approach as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is going to help, but you could make something like a fluent interface so that you can construct the message like this:

```
string msg = Parameters("name1", value1).And("name2", value2).ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

This is neither elegant nor rubust, but you can still pass "parameter names" implicitly:

```
public void Test()
{
    var foo = "bla";
    var bar = "blub";

    var msg = Parameters(() => foo).And(() => bar).ToString();
    // msg contains now "foo = bla, bar = blub"
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class Params
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _params = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Params And(Expression<Func<object>> exp)
    {
        var body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        _params[body.Member.Name] = exp.Compile().Invoke();
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(", ", _params.Select(pair => String.Format("{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)));
    }
}

public Params Parameters(Expression<Func<object>>expr)
{
    return new Params().And(expr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. I'm looking to, ideally, be implicit about the name of each parameter in the message. That seems to be what I'm getting at.